# SwiftUI view won't expand to full height - iOS 15 Xcode 13 beta 5

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create my own keyboard view (I need a decimal keyboard, with a guaranteed `.` and not `,` which is shown in Europe).

I have it working great except in landscape one of the keys is not the correct size.
(Colours to show frame sizes)

[image]
[image]

The problem seems to happen on iOS 15 when the height of the full view shrinks to around 200px. On iOS 14 you can see it's causing issue as it has padding on the bottom row. Removing the `.resizable()` form the Image seems to fix that so not sure if it's related.

I've simplified the code here to a view that shows the issue.

Here is the code that builds each key:

```
enum KeyboardKey: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case one = "1"
    case two = "2"
    case three = "3"
    case four = "4"
    case five = "5"
    case six = "6"
    case seven = "7"
    case eight = "8"
    case nine = "9"
    case zero = "0"
    case dot = "."
    case backspace = "backspace"
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven,
                .eight, .nine, .zero:
            Text(self.rawValue)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
        case .dot:
            Text(self.rawValue)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(6)
        case .backspace:
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(6)
        }
    }
}
```

and the keyboard view is built up with this:

```
struct IPKeyboardButtons: View {
    
    let rows: [[KeyboardKey]] = [
        [.one, .two, .three],
        [.four, .five, .six],
        [.seven, .eight, .nine],
        [.dot, .zero, .backspace]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<rows.count, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                
                let row = rows[rowIndex]
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(row, id: \.self) { key in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Tapped: \(key)")
                        }) {
                            key.view()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(5)
        .padding(.bottom, 40)
        .background(Color.keyboardBackground)
    }
}
```

You can view it in a SwiftUI preview with this:

```
struct App_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IPKeyboardButtons()
            .frame(height: 200)
    }
}
```

Removing the `.frame(height: 200)` make it look perfect.

I've tried using a `ZStack`, `VStack`, `AnyView()` you name it, to wrap the key, but they all have the same effect.
I want the image to be smaller than the button, so I set it to be 20x20 then set the container view to `.infinity` but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be helpful. You left `rows` out or your code.

Comment: You are right, I assumed I was missing something really obvious but have now added the full code for the keyboard.

Comment: Have you considered, just replacing coma with dot in text field instead of creating custom keyboard?

Comment: It's for entering IP addresses. Yes I could use the decimal keypad but the user will see a comma when they know they want to press a dot. It's not a great UX

Comment: I've just twigged that this could be an iOS beta issue. I'm using Xcode 13 beta 5. I've just built it with Xcode 12 and the spacing is all over the place, but that button looks fine.

Comment: I've completely simplified the code in the question so it is just a view. The problem is definitely with the `Image` in 1 of the buttons.

Comment: I took your code and ran it. It was not quite buildable, as you were using custom colors, so I substituted standard colors. I also put the keyboard in another view with a textfield and a `Spacer()` with a `.frame(height: 200)` ( I like a natural looking preview) and ran it as a device preview in preview. I got something different still. The code runs fine in portrait. In landscape, the last row of buttons are all the same size, but there is a gap from the numbers to the last row. Unless your are putting the keyboard in a frame, I would use the frame elsewhere to debug. Xcode 12.5.

Comment: Yes in Xcode 12.5 it gives that result. And the offender is the Image in the last key. Change it `Text("a")` and it works fine. Xcode 13 looks slightly different, but agin it's the `Image` causing the issue.

Comment: Do you need to support iOS 13?

Comment: No, this is actually going to be iOS 15+ only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `LazyVGrid` to handle this. The solution you are trying to use was really an iOS 13 workaround for making grids. `LazyVGrid` handles this elegantly.

```
struct IPKeyboardButtons: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(KeyboardKey.allCases, id: \.self) { key in
                Button(action: {
                    print("Tapped: \(key)")
                }) {
                    key.view()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(5)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

I changed the enums `view()` function slightly to add some padding around the symbols(number or SF Font). Also, you can treat an SF Font like text. They are designed to be used right along with text and using text modifiers like `.font`:

```
enum KeyboardKey: String, CaseIterable {
    
    case one = "1"
    case two = "2"
    case three = "3"
    case four = "4"
    case five = "5"
    case six = "6"
    case seven = "7"
    case eight = "8"
    case nine = "9"
    case zero = "0"
    case dot = "."
    case backspace = "backspace"
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven,
                .eight, .nine, .zero:
            Text(self.rawValue)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding() // optional, but this will increase the size of the button itself
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.5), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 1)
        case .dot:
            Text(self.rawValue)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding() // optional, but this will increase the size of the button itself
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(6)
        case .backspace:
            Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                .font(.title)
                .background(Color.green)
                .padding() // optional, but this will increase the size of the button itself
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(6)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view I put it in so it would behave in a real world test case. I would stay away from forcing frames in the preview as that will give artificial constraints and does not respect safe areas:

```
struct KeyboardView: View {
    
    @State var textBinding = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("TextField", text: $textBinding)
            Spacer()
            IPKeyboardButtons()
        }
    }
}
```

This code is much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I saw the notification that said "I would use a `LazyVGrid`" I added the `LazyVGrid` to my project and it worked :) I will look though and add some of your changes too, but the Lazy grid was the answer. Thank you